# Regex match non-greedy on one optional string and greedy on another

Tags: regex, pcre

I've researched around for a while and haven't found a clue for matching the following pattern (I am also very new to regex, though), it looks either like

```
/abc/foo/bar(/*)
```

or

```
/abc/foo/bar/stop
```

So I want to match and capture the above string as /abc/foo/bar. Now "/stop" is an optional string that could be appended at the end of the pattern. The goal is to get the desired capture while ignoring "stop" if they present (and if "stop" exists multiple times stop at the first "stop"), while allow as many slashes in the middle as possible except the slash at the end of line.

If I simply do:

```
^(/.*[^/])/*$
```

Which is greedy in including all slashes until I strip off the possible last occurrence; but in order to accept the second case where I have an optional "/stop", I need to match in a non-greedy way until I find the first possible "/stop" and stop there.

How can I craft a single regex that matches both cases?

EDIT: Not sure if my previous example wasn't clear enough. Try to give more, say I want to match and capture "/abc/foo/bar" in all of the following strings:

```
/abc/foo/bar
/abc/foo/bar/
/abc/foo/bar///
/abc/foo/bar/stop
/abc/foo/bar/stop/foo/bar/stop/stop
/abc/foo/bar//stop
```

While it won't match any of the followings:

```
/abc/foo/bar/sto (will match the whole "/abc/foo/bar/sto" instead)
/abc/foo/bar/abc/foo/bar (it will catch "/abc/foo/bar/abc/foo/bar" instead)
```

Let me know if this is clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give some examples?

Comment: Please tag the language you're using for the regex

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend against trying to do too much with one regular expression. The point of a regex is to make your code easier to understand by more concisely matching a complex pattern. Two or three simple regular expressions could be used to solve this issue and your could would be better off.

Comment: @zzzzBov I added pcre as tag, but I don't mind people giving general solutions that works for all languages :-) and thanks for the point of combining simple regex, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(?:\/+(?!$|(?:stop\/?))[^\/]+)*/
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lP9bD1/2)

Explanation:

This matches the start of the string (`^`), followed by zero or more instances of the following pattern:

- one or more slashes (`\/+`) that are not followed by the end of the string (`$`) or by `stop`, followed by
- one or more non-slash characters (`[^\/]+`)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Here's a [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Dg2ETxQG_9DeIo_c) with working unit tests.

**EDIT:** Here is an alternative, arguably simpler, regex:

```
/^.+?(?=\/*$|\/+stop\b)/
```

This matches one or more characters in a non-greedy manner, then stops when whatever is after the match is one of the following:

1. the end of the string (`$`), possibly preceded by one or more slashes (`\/*`)
2. one or more slashes, the word stop, and a word break.

Here's a [Regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fH7tY0/2) of this option.

**EDIT 2:** If you'd like to test this, here's a simple JavaScript test that tests the second regex above against various test strings and logs the results to the console:

```
var re = /^.+?(?=\/*$|\/+stop\b)/,
    test_strings = ["/abc/foo/bar",
                    "/abc/foo/bar/",
                    "/abc/foo/bar///",
                    "/abc/foo/bar/stop",
                    "/abc/foo/bar/stop/foo/bar/stop/stop",
                    "/abc/foo/bar//stop",
                    "/abc/foo/bar/sto",
                    "/abc/foo/bar/abc/foo/bar"];
for(var s = 0; s < test_strings.length; s++) {
    console.log(test_strings[s].match(re)[0]);
}

/*
Results:

/abc/foo/bar
/abc/foo/bar
/abc/foo/bar
/abc/foo/bar
/abc/foo/bar
/abc/foo/bar
/abc/foo/bar/sto
/abc/foo/bar/abc/foo/bar 

*/
```

Comment: (OP asked about `/abc/foo/bar$/stop` but has deleted that comment...) In that case, it would match `/abc/foo/bar$`. [Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OVRt0J54ydqff24E)

Comment: Thanks very much for this. As I am fairly new now I understand those lookahead stuff as well. I like solution 2 since it's really much simpler. I can see the trick is convert one of the greedy case into lazy as well. Does lazy match really lot worse in performance than greedy match? And plus I want both "match and capture" so by adding a pair of parenthesis around ".+?" does the job. While for the first one I actually can't get the capture right, even ^((\/+(?!$|(?:stop\/?))[^\/]+)*) and just take $1 still doesn't show exactly right in that demo (it somehow groups first two strings together)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
^((?:/[^/]+)+?)(?:/+|/+stop(?:/.*)?)$
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/wY7mO6/2)

and if atomic groups are available, you better write:

```
^((?:/[^/]+)+?)(?>/+$|/+stop(?:/.*)?)
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/uM2qR4/1)

If lookaheads are available:

```
^/(?>[^/]+|/(?!/*(?:$|stop(?:/|$))))+
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/bM8oJ8/1)

ps: don't forget to escape slashes if your delimiters are slashes.

As Ed Cottrell notices it, features like atomic grouping are not available in language like Javascript or in the re module of Python. However, this feature can be efficiently emulated using the fact that a lookahead is naturaly atomic: `(?>a+)` <=> `(?=(a+))\1`

Comment: The first two match too much (they include `/stop` if present). Also, the last two are PCRE only; they won't work in, for example, JavaScript. The versions in my answer work in JavaScript and do not capture a trailing `/stop`.

Comment: @EdCottrell: absolutly not! Wait a minute, I will add demos for you.

Comment: Your demos prove my point; the matched *groups* only match the desired text, but the overall matches include the entire strings on each line. And the last two examples definitely do not work in JavaScript, but throw syntax errors.

Comment: Compare this demo, which does not match `/stop` or trailing slashes: http://regex101.com/r/fH7tY0/2

Comment: @EdCottrell: You didn't understand that the three patterns use a capturing group to extract the needed part of the string. For these three pattern, I don't care if the end of the string is part of the global match or not, it's only cosmetic. The fact that the two last pattern use an atomic group is not really a problem, since it can be adapted for Javascript or Python with a trick to emulate an atomic group. I will add an example to illustrate that.

Comment: I understand what your solutions are trying to do, and I understand why you used capturing groups. The point is that the regex nonetheless matches the entire string. The captured subgroup contains the desired text, but the match is against the entire string. As for the last two, it's not about atomic subgroups or the fact that they could be modified to work for various regex flavors; they throw syntax errors as written if used on a non-PCRE flavor.

Comment: @EdCottrell: A non-PCRE flavor? Do you mean Java, Ruby, C#, Visual C++, VB.net, Perl, new regex module for Python... I don't think. But if I follow your idea of the most portable pattern, all the patterns on this page don't work with a POSIX regex engine: MySQL, grep, sed, clish *(I learned this today)*, posix module for python, basic mode for TCL, basic mode for R...

Comment: By non-PCRE, I mean anything that implements regex differently from how [the PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org/) does it. For example, [PCRE supports](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) positive and negative lookbehind assertions and backtracking controls like `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)`. Regex flavors that are PCRE-like, but not fully compliant, don't always support these things. For example, neither JavaScript nor VBScript supports the features I just listed.

Comment: To clarify, Perl, PHP, and many other flavors of regex will support all three of your examples just fine. But others will not. In my opinion, answers to regex-related questions should be as portable as possible, especially when the language in which regex will be used is not specified.

Comment: @EdCottrell: To clarify, in my turn, the entire first list supports these three patterns, and all these languages don't use a PCRE engine. Each time we write a pattern, we need to impose a limit for portability. In the present case there is no limit! In my worst nightmares, the OP may be using vim syntax or if it is a regex engine he did himself. All that to say that portability is an illusion.

Comment: My case is just pcre, forgot to tag that originally, my bad. But I appreciate the effort in providing solutions that are as portable as possible.

Comment: @Superziyi: No problem, and I think that it is a good thing that this forum gives the opportunity to disprove what I wrote in my answer. Ed Cottrell is welcome.